# how J2V8 returns Big integer?

Tags: node.js, v8, j2v8

At present I am using v8 version below for my windows: com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8_win32_x86_64:4.6.0.

I want to return Big integer but looks like this version does not support Big Int.
return {'result' : BigInt('893800399029639267')};
This does not return anything.

Other options like below also does not work:
const value = 893800399029639267n
This gives error.

Kindly suggest, how can I return BigInt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigInt was introduced in 6.7 my dude.

It looks like you're on 4.6

https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-67

Comment: soz my dude looks like they stopped in 2016 https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/releases

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out about an alternative to J2V8 called [javet](https://github.com/caoccao/Javet). I recommend checking it out. It supports BigInt, it's actively maintained and is up to date with node.js LTS